# Change Some Colors of Email body in Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, email, html-email

I am trying to change the color of some texts in the body of my email by using MIMEMultipart.
the purpose of this python code is to change the color in some circumstances. so if the word "days" is in the dictionary so the color should be something, and if not the color should be black.But unfortunately it sends only the last value of dictionary, but not all the values.
should mention that in case of printing , it shows all the values correctly.

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = 'License Checker'
me = msg['From'] = "python@mail.com"
you = msg['To'] = "me@mail.com"
for key, value in my_dic.items():
    if 'days' in value:
        html1 = 'Expiration Date : \n {}{} \n\n '.format(key,value) + '\n'
        msg.attach(MIMEText(html1, "html"))
    if 'days' not in value:
        html = """<html>
                <head></head>
                  <body>
                    <p style="color: red;">""" + key + value + """</p>
                  </body>
                </html>
                """
        msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html'))
server = smtplib.SMTP('a.b.c.d')
server.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: I could not replicate the error without an smtp server. I did `print(msg)` after the loop and it looks like it considers all the values of the dict. Can you edit the question to show the message being sent?

Comment: I have no problem with print(msg) too. The problem is while sending the mail.

Comment: first in `for`-loop create one `html` with all information and after `for`-loop  attache this single HTML to mail.

Comment: @furas Could you please let me show by example.

Comment: don't you know how to concatenate strings ? `"<p>...</p>" + "<p>...</p>" `? or `html = html + "<p>...</p>"`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but mail may expect only one HTML attachement as alternative for plain text so create one HTML string with all information and create only one attachement.

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = 'License Checker'
me = msg['From'] = "python@mail.com"
you = msg['To'] = "me@mail.com"

html = '<html><head></head><body>'

for key, value in my_dic.items():
    if 'days' in value:
        html += 'Expiration Date : \n {}{} \n\n \n'.format(key, value)
    else:
        html += '<p style="color: red;">{}{}</p>'.format(key, value)

html +=  '</body></html>'

msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html'))

server = smtplib.SMTP('a.b.c.d')
server.send_message(msg)
```